# How to divide all previous observations by the last observation iteratively within a data frame column by group in R and then store the result

Tags: r, iteration, grouping

I have the following data frame:

```
data <- data.frame("Group" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
"Days" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4), "Num" = c(10,12,23,30,34,40,50,60,2,4,8,12))
```

I need to take the last value in Num and divide it by all of the preceding values. Then, I need to move to the second to the last value in Num and do the same, until I reach the first value in each group.

Edited based on the comments below:
In plain language and showing all the math, starting with the first group as suggested below, I am trying to achieve the following: 
Take 60 (last value in group 1) and:

```
Day Num Res
7 60/50  1.2
6 60/40  1.5
5 60/34  1.76
4 60/30  2
3 60/23  2.60
2 60/12  5
1 60/10  6
```

Then keep only the row that has the value 2, as I don't care about the others (I want the value that is greater or equal to 2 that is the closest to 2) and return the day of that value, which is 4, as well. Then, move on to 50 and do the following:

```
Day Num Res
6 50/40  1.25
5 50/34  1.47
4 50/30  1.67
3 50/23  2.17
2 50/12  4.17
1 50/10  5
```

Then keep only the row that has the value 2.17 and return the day of that value, which is 3, as well. Then, move on to 40 and do the same thing over again, move on to 34, then 30, then 23, then 12, the last value (or Day 1 value) I don't care about. Then move on to the next group's last value (12) and repeat the same approach for that group (12/8, 12/4, 12/2; 8/4, 8/2; 4/2)

I would like to store the results of these divisions but only the most recent result that is greater than or equal to 2. I would also like to return the day that result was achieved. Basically, I am trying to calculate doubling time for each day. I would also need this to be grouped by the Group. Normally, I would use dplyr for this but I am not sure how to link up a loop with dyplr to take advantage of group_by. Also, I could be overlooking lapply or some variation thereof. My expected dataframe with the results would ideally be this:

```
data2 <- data.frame(divres = c(NA,NA,2.3,2.5,2.833333333,3.333333333,2.173913043,2,NA,2,2,3), 
obs_n =c(NA,NA,1,2,2,2,3,4,NA,1,2,2))

data3 <- bind_cols(data, data2)
```

I have tried this first loop to calculate the division but I am lost as to how to move on to the next last value within each group. Right now, this is ignoring the group, though I obviously have not told it to group as I am unclear as to how to do this outside of dplyr.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) 
   data$test[i] <- ifelse(!is.na(data$Num), last(data$Num)/data$Num[i] , NA)
```

I also get the following error when I run it:
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

To store the division, I have tried this:

```
division <- function(x){
  if(x>=2){
    return(x)
  } else {
    return(FALSE)
  }
}
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
   data$test[i]<- division(data$test[i])
}
```

Now, this approach works but only if i need to run this once on the last observation and only if I apply it to 1 group. I have 209 groups and many days that I would need to run this over. I am not sure how to put together the first for loop with the division function and I also am totally lost as to how to do this by group and move to the next last values. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say *"divide it by all of the preceding values"*, does that mean on the first iteration, you start with `60` and then (dividing by all preceding) do `60/50/40/34/30/23/12/10` (which is `1.065644e-08`)? That seems a bit odd to me ... I might be reading your text too literally.

Comment: I think `dplyr` is simple enough, including `grouping`, I suggest you just talk about a single vector of a single group, say `c(10, 12, 23, 30, 34, 40, 50, 60)`, and explain verbatim what you expect to happen to that vector, in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your `division` function to handle vector and return a dataframe with two columns `divres`  and `ind` the latter is the row index that will be used to calculate `obs_n` as shown below:

```
    division <- function(x){
  lenx <- length(x)
  y    <- vector(mode="numeric", length = lenx)
  z    <- vector(mode="numeric", length = lenx)
  for (i in lenx:1){
    y[i] <- ifelse(length(which(x[i]/x[1:i]>=2))==0,NA,x[i]/x[1:i] [max(which(x[i]/x[1:i]>=2))])
    z[i] <- ifelse(is.na(y[i]),NA,max(which(x[i]/x[1:i]>=2)))
  }
  df <- data.frame(divres = y, ind = z)
  return(df)
}
```

> Check the output of `division` function created above using `data$Num` as input

```
> division(data$Num)
     divres ind
1        NA  NA
2        NA  NA
3  2.300000   1
4  2.500000   2
5  2.833333   2
6  3.333333   2
7  2.173913   3
8  2.000000   4
9        NA  NA
10 2.000000   9
11 2.000000  10
12 3.000000  10
```

> Use `cbind` to combine the above output with dataframe `data1`, use `pipes` and `mutate` from `dplyr` to lookup the `obs_n` value in `Day` using `ind`, select appropriate columns to generate the desired dataframe `data2`:

```
data2 <- cbind.data.frame(data, division(data$Num)) %>% mutate(obs_n = Days[ind]) %>% select(-ind)
```

> Output

```
> data2
   Group Days Num   divres obs_n
1      1    1  10       NA    NA
2      1    2  12       NA    NA
3      1    3  23 2.300000     1
4      1    4  30 2.500000     2
5      1    5  34 2.833333     2
6      1    6  40 3.333333     2
7      1    7  50 2.173913     3
8      1    8  60 2.000000     4
9      2    1   2       NA    NA
10     2    2   4 2.000000     1
11     2    3   8 2.000000     2
12     2    4  12 3.000000     2
```

Comment: @Maggie I think your question may have changed since this answer. I am curious whether this solution is what you were looking for.

Comment: @ Maggie can you clarify how you calculate `obs_n`?

Comment: thank you for writing this up, I will double check it when my brain is working and get back to you. As to obs_n, this is the day on which the result of 2+ occurs. So, for example, when dividing into 60 the value of 2.0 was obtained on Day 4 so ideally the loop would return 4 for the value of obs_n. For dividing into 50, the result of 2.17 occurred on Day 3, so that would be the value returned to obs_n. I don't know if this is making any sense. Now that i write this up, don't tell me how you would do it. I would like to try it myself and come back if I get stumped!

Comment: thank you for the write up, I am confirming that this works well with my data. I am going to study up so that I can fully understand the structure of the loop and how it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function with a for loop to get the desired day as given below. Then use that to get the divres in a **dplyr** mutation.

```
obs_n <- function(x, days) {
  lst <- list()
  for(i in length(x):1){
    obs <- days[which(rev(x[i]/x[(i-1):1]) >= 2)]
    if(length(obs)==0)
     lst[[i]] <- NA
    else
      lst[[i]] <- max(obs)
  }
  unlist(lst)
}
```

Then use `dense_rank` to obtain the row number corresponding to each `obs_n`. This is needed in case the days are not consecutive, i.e. have gaps.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(obs_n=obs_n(Num, Days), divres=Num/Num[dense_rank(obs_n)])
```

---

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   Group [2]
   Group  Days   Num obs_n divres
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1     1    10    NA  NA   
 2     1     2    12    NA  NA   
 3     1     3    23     1   2.3 
 4     1     4    30     2   2.5 
 5     1     5    34     2   2.83
 6     1     6    40     2   3.33
 7     1     7    50     3   2.17
 8     1     8    60     4   2   
 9     2     1     2    NA  NA   
10     2     2     4     1   2   
11     2     3     8     2   2   
12     2     4    12     2   3
```

---

Explanation of dense ranks (from Wikipedia).
In **dense** ranking, items that compare equally receive the same ranking number, and the next item(s) receive the immediately following ranking number.

```
x <- c(NA, NA, 1,2,2,4,6)
dplyr::dense_rank(x)
# [1] NA, NA, 1 2 2 3 4
```

Compare with rank (default method="average"). Note that NAs are included at the end by default.

```
rank(x)
[1] 6.0 7.0 1.0 2.5 2.5 4.0 5.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not working for me at this moment, but I am sure that is because I am applying it wrong to my actual data. I will work on it more this weekend to see what the issue is.

Comment: Seens that there may be something about your actual data that is different to the sample data you provided.